# HMAC SHA-256 difference between Java and PHP

Tags: java, php, cryptography, sha256, hmac

I am trying to connect to a web services and I need to encrypt my signature.

My java method for doing so is as follows:

```
public String hashMacSha256(String message, String key) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(),"HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
    String hash = Base64.encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return hash;
}
```

The php function which I was provided with is

```
$signature=base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", trim($xmlReq), $signature_key, True));
```

```
Java result: YN3JXxIbcispA+smV6zUu6KVNwnm+cBmMmSNqAbVoS0=
Php result:  x7WuslORVY00BtoQuk1dya2bu9pMCpPMunPqPR+3HI4=
```

When I run both to compare the result they are different. Is it because the java function is wrong or?

Comment: First things first.... `$signature_key == secret_key` ?

Comment: $signature_key=trim($private_key.$ApiPassword.$TransactionId);

Comment: They all have default values which i know before hand

Comment: Yes, *you* know, *we don't*. Secondly I was asking if the keys are the same, not if both languages default to their default value. Then I really would suggest taking a look at `trim()` on PHP's end. Are you trimming ANY values in Java? I don't see it, do you?

Comment: Output and compare byte[] of message and key. `message.getByte()` and `key.getByte()` will use system default encoding in java.

Comment: @pavlos You provide the outputs, but you forgot to add the inputs.